# XtraGrid Move Grid Row Up and Down

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

As described in this [DevExpress thread](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q450665), I was able to move grid rows up and down. But as soon as I added table from database with **Primary Key** constraint, it stopped working. Throwing exception:

> Column 'Id' is constrained to be unique. Value '101' is already present

This is my **MoveDown** code:

```
Private Sub BtnMveDwn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnMveDwn.Click

    Dim lObjGrdVew As GridView
    Dim lObjDtaTbl As DataTable
    Dim lIntIndex As Integer
    Dim lObjTmpRow As Object
    Try
        lObjGrdVew = CType(GrdCntrlMain.FocusedView, GridView)
        lObjDtaTbl = TryCast(GrdCntrlMain.DataSource, DataTable)
        lIntIndex = lObjGrdVew.FocusedRowHandle

        lObjGrdVew.GridControl.Focus()

        If lIntIndex >= lObjGrdVew.DataRowCount - 1 Then
            Return
        End If

        lObjTmpRow = lObjDtaTbl(lObjGrdVew.ViewRowHandleToDataSourceIndex(lIntIndex + 1)).ItemArray

        lObjDtaTbl(lObjGrdVew.ViewRowHandleToDataSourceIndex(lIntIndex + 1)).ItemArray = lObjDtaTbl(lObjGrdVew.ViewRowHandleToDataSourceIndex(lIntIndex)).ItemArray

        lObjDtaTbl(lObjGrdVew.ViewRowHandleToDataSourceIndex(lIntIndex)).ItemArray = lObjTmpRow

        lObjGrdVew.FocusedRowHandle += 1
        lObjGrdVew.UnselectRow(lObjGrdVew.FocusedRowHandle - 1)
        lObjGrdVew.SelectRow(lObjGrdVew.FocusedRowHandle)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub
```

As for this [thread](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2343), I haven't tried but of course if number of columns are higher, I have to go through all columns. i.e, Looping.

Thanks

**EDIT 1** Please, no drag/drop code. I am doing it on Button click.

---

**EDIT 2** 
There is a problem! I have rows with dim and visible **Expand** buttons. Like, if there is exist child row then expand button will be proper visible but dim otherwise just like normal grid behavior. But when rows are swapped, expand buttons doesn't change their state which is wrong and undesirable. Can you sort out the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`DataTable.BeginLoadData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.beginloaddata(v=vs.110).aspx) method and [`DataTable.EndLoadData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.endloaddata(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The `DataTable.BeginLoadData` method turns off notifications, index maintenance, and constraints while loading data, and `DataTable.EndLoadData` turns its on.
Here is example:

```
Private Sub BtnMveDwn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnMveDwn.Click

    Dim lObjGrdVew As GridView
    Dim lObjDtaTbl As DataTable
    Dim lIntIndex As Integer
    Dim lObjTmpRow As Object
    Try
        lObjGrdVew = CType(GrdCntrlMain.FocusedView, GridView)
        lObjDtaTbl = TryCast(GrdCntrlMain.DataSource, DataTable)
        lIntIndex = lObjGrdVew.FocusedRowHandle

        lObjGrdVew.GridControl.Focus()

        If lIntIndex >= lObjGrdVew.DataRowCount - 1 Then
            Return
        End If

        lObjTmpRow = lObjDtaTbl(lObjGrdVew.ViewRowHandleToDataSourceIndex(lIntIndex + 1)).ItemArray

        lObjDtaTbl.BeginLoadData '<= turn off constraints

        lObjDtaTbl(lObjGrdVew.ViewRowHandleToDataSourceIndex(lIntIndex + 1)).ItemArray = lObjDtaTbl(lObjGrdVew.ViewRowHandleToDataSourceIndex(lIntIndex)).ItemArray

        lObjDtaTbl(lObjGrdVew.ViewRowHandleToDataSourceIndex(lIntIndex)).ItemArray = lObjTmpRow

        lObjDtaTbl.EndLoadData '<= turn on constraints

        GrdCntrlMain.RefreshDataSource() '<= update GridControl to reflect the changes

        lObjGrdVew.FocusedRowHandle += 1
        lObjGrdVew.UnselectRow(lObjGrdVew.FocusedRowHandle - 1)
        lObjGrdVew.SelectRow(lObjGrdVew.FocusedRowHandle)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub
```

**EDIT 2**
You need to update your `GridControl` by using `GrdCntrlMain.RefreshDataSource`, so the changes in your underlying data source will be correctly reflected in your `DataControl`.

Comment: Thanks, it is working! According this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3bxwk8b.aspx You can also use `dataSet1.EnforceConstraints = False` and after, `dataSet1.EnforceConstraints = True`

Comment: @FaizanMubasher Yes, but in your question there are nothing about `DataSet`.

Comment: I know! I just found it before your answer :-) . Never mind

Comment: There is a problem! I have rows with dim and visible **Expand** buttons. Like, if there is exist child row then expand button will be proper visible but dim otherwise just like normal grid behavior. But when rows are swapped, expand buttons doesn't change their state which is wrong and undesirable. Can you sort out the issue?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher Try to use [`GridView.InvalidateRow`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_InvalidateRowtopic) method on both rows.

Comment: @FaizanMubasher Ok. I have included it into the answer.